# How to reload UIView after closing UIAlertController

Tags: swift, uiview, uialertcontroller

I try to make BarChart using https://github.com/CoreCharts/CoreCharts I have a button, which call UIAlertController with textField. 
After I click submit button, new data is added to the array. I need the diagram to reboot.

```
@IBAction func newWeightButton(_ sender: Any) {
        //updateGraph()
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter your new weight", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField()


        let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { [unowned alert] _ in
            let textField = alert.textFields![0]
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
            textField.becomeFirstResponder()
            let answer = Double(textField.text!)
            self.weightArr.append(answer!)
            print(self.weightArr)
            self.loadCoreChartData()
        }

        alert.addAction(submitAction)

        present(alert, animated: true)

}



func loadCoreChartData() -> [CoreChartEntry] {

        return getWeightList()

    }
func getWeightList()->[CoreChartEntry] {
    var allResults = [CoreChartEntry]()


    //let days = ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thur","Fri"]
    let plateNumber = [80,75,90,88,84]
    var count = self.weightArr.count
    for index in 0..<count {

        let newEntry = CoreChartEntry(id: "\(self.weightArr[index])",
            barTitle: "Day",
            barHeight: Double(self.weightArr[index]),
            barColor:  UIColor(red: 0, green: 122/255, blue: 1, alpha: 1))


        allResults.append(newEntry)

    }
```

Comment: How do you add this array to view ?

Answer (score 0):

For CoreCharts, call `reload()` on the chart.

Generally, in iOS, setting properties of the `UIView` is sufficient to get it to update, but with views that use a datasource of some type (like tables, collection views, and core charts), there is usually some kind of reload...() function to tell the view that the datasource changed.